# append DOM node

Tags: jquery

im having problems with appending DOM nodes..

this doesn't work:

```
this.loader = $(document.body).append('<div class="loader" style="display:none">loader</div>');

$(this.loader).fadeIn(1000);
```

but this works:

```
this.loader = DOM.div(document.body);
with(this.loader){
    className = 'loader';
    innerHTML = 'loader';
    style.display = 'none';
}

$(this.loader).fadeIn(1000);
```

can anybody tell me what is wrong?!

but if I do like this the div gets added and its visible

```
this.loader = $(document.body).append('<div class="loader">loader</div>');
```

Comment: `DOM.div(...)`? That does not look like (just) jQuery to me.

Comment: its because its my own DOM constructor :)

Comment: Since [jQuery core can take a map of properties](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) (and a whole bunch of other nice stuff, like event bindings), why wouldn't you just use that instead? Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/otoze5/edit).

Comment: Please **add here the link to the REAL question about title, or change title**: jQuery append DOM node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) returns the jQuery object for the selector / object you passed into it, so your first line is getting the jQuery object around `document.body`, not the jQuery wrapper for your new `div`. You probably want [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo):

```
this.loader = $('<div class="loader" style="display:none">loader</div>').appendTo(document.body);
this.loader.fadeIn(1000);
```

Or the longer (but perhaps clearer way):

```
this.loader = $('<div class="loader" style="display:none">loader</div>');
this.loader.appendTo(document.body);
this.loader.fadeIn(1000);
```

Also note that what you get back is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to use `$()` on it.

Comment: thanks.. but how can you then in jQuery remove/delete a DOM node?

Comment: @clarkk: Delete? Your question was about creation, wasn't it? But to remove a DOM element, you can use jQuery's `remove` function.

Answer (score 1):

The append function does not return the value you are thinking of I believe. You should do something like this:

```
 var myDiv = $('<div class="loader" style="display:none">loader</div>');
 $(document.body).append(myDiv);

 myDiv.fadeIn(1000);
```